# Two same queries to find duplicate records return diffrent result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries two find the duplicate records but they are returning different results, on the same table

Query 1 Returns 17 rows

`SELECT minimumexperience
    FROM minimumexperience
    GROUP BY minimumexperience
    HAVING COUNT(minimumexperience) > 1`

Query 2 Returns 22 rows

```
 SELECT b.id
FROM
(
    SELECT id, 
           minimumexperience, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lower(Trim(minimumexperience))
           ORDER BY minimumexperience) AS counts
    FROM minimumexperience --ORDER BY dbo.minimumexperience.minimumexperience ASC   
) AS b
WHERE b.counts > 1
```

Comment: Please include some sample data.

Comment: `lower(Trim(minimumexperience))` might not be the same as `minimumexperience`...

Answer (score 2):

One explanation is that if a given `minimumexperience` value could occur *more* than twice, e.g. three or four times, then your second query would return *all* duplicates besides the first one.  For example, if there were four records with a certain value of `minimumexperience`:

```
minimumexperience | ROW_NUMBER
10                | 1
10                | 2
10                | 3
10                | 4
```

Then the first query would report one duplicate, while the second would report *three* duplicates, because three records have a row number greater than one.

Another explanation is that your call to `LOWER` and `TRIM` in the second query is bucketing several previously different values of `minimumexperience` together, which then yields something similar to the above.  That is, consider the following three values:

```
minimumexperience | ROW_NUMBER
One               | 1
one               | 2
ONE               | 3
```

In the first query, the above three records are all unique, but in the second query all three are being mapped to `one`, and would therefore generate two duplicates.

If you really wanted to do this using analytic functions, because you wanted to find all duplicate records, then `COUNT` would be more appropriate:

```
SELECT b.id
FROM
(
    SELECT id, minimumexperience, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY minimumexperience) cnt
    FROM minimumexperience
) AS b
WHERE b.counts > 1;
```